# Can i receive local TV with apple tv in the antenna port?

Tags: appletv

Can I receive broadcast TV with Apple TV connected to my television in the antenna port as an Internet provider?

Comment: As cable tv or as internet tv ? sorry, where is the apple tv plugged in to

Comment: An ether net cable is plugged into cable modem and hdmi cable goes from modem to tv

Comment: Apple TV doesn't have any support for broadcast TV so can you please clarify how your Apple TV is involved in the setup you have? Also you may try to get broadcast TV working without the Apple TV connected.

Comment: I detached the antenna in cable and reattached it and now I'm getting several sub channels inc luding kcet which is on 23--215!